# How can I replace all zeroes returned with blank space

Tags: sql, oracle

How can I remove all zeros returnd from an sql query

edit: My table has a lot of cells that contain 0. i want all zeros to be replaced by a blank space

for example:

**location |count**

location1 | 0

localtion2| 2

**turned into**

**location |count**

location1 |

localtion2| 2

Comment: I think you have to be a bit more specific in your question. Perhaps even provide an example?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The function is oddly enough named REPLACE. Check Oracle's documentation here: http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions134.htm

`SELECT REPLACE(COLUMN_NAME,'0',' ') "Column Name" FROM YOUR_TABLE_NAME;`

Comment: How can I select multiple columns with this method?

Comment: Just use a comma and specify the other columns you want.

SELECT REPLACE(COLUMN_ONE, '0', ' ') "Column One", REPLACE(COLUMN_TWO, '0', ' ') "Column Two", COLUMN_THREE FROM YOUR_TABLE_NAME;

Comment: This will convert 10203 to '1 2 3'.

Answer (score 2):

I assume you mean leading zeros?  Try ltrim:

```
select ltrim('00001234', '0') from dual;
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the case statement maybe ?

```
SELECT 
    CASE 
        WHEN numbers = 0 THEN "Zero" 
        WHEN numbers = -1 THEN "Under zero"
        ELSE "Not Empty" 
    END
FROM t_able
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT DECODE(n, 0, ' ', n) ...
```